# CSS in sub static folder not working properly in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-settings

I know it's a simple problem but I want to know what I missed. I'm sure the solution is simple.

Here's the problem:

settings.py:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

The tree with the problem:

```
    ├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   │   └── style.css
│   └── js
└── templates
    ├── hi.html
```

.html file:

```
  {% load static %}

  <!DOCTYPE html>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}">
```

and the boom does not work but some codes work and some do not. I'm not quite sure what's going on there.
when there is no subfolder:

```
    ├── manage.py
├── static
│   ├── bootstrap.min.css
│   └── style.css
└── templates
    ├── hi.html
```

and when I use it this way it works fine!

```
{% load static %}

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'bootstrap.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'cstyle.css' %}">
```

Am I really missing something? I'm not sure, I haven't opened a project from scratch with django for a long time.

Comment: After doing with sub-folder you should check via ctrl+U, in the page source that css is linking or not you should click to css file and check whether opening or not?

Comment: Try adding a subfolder with the application name, (eg static->app_name->css->main.css) In template: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'app_name/css/style.css' %}">

Comment: I have been using this method proposed by @sk1p since I started my Django journey. It never fails.

Comment: @SunderamDubey css or related files appear in the page source. As I said, some lines work, some do not.

Comment: @j4nus And I think for second option, it would  be working perfectly, isn't it?

Comment: @sk1p but I have a question here, what should I do for different applications? For example, when placing the js files for base.html, won't it be correct to do this in the js folder under the main static folder?

Comment: @SunderamDubey It worked, but I couldn't quite grasp the logic. I had previously continued all the work with the method in the question. Why did this happen now? Of course, also curious about the answer to the above comment.

Comment: @j4nus Which comment are you talking about?

Comment: @j4nus Read the documentation about "collectstatic"
In short, Django puts all static files in production into one folder at the root of the project, and so that these files do not overwrite each other, such a structure is used as I described above. When developing in the root of the project, I create folders for basic html templates and basic css and js